# Why the element fail to align in center vertically in <div>/<a>/<i>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a fixed position, vertical tool bar in the right bottom of the page. Icon-fonts ***(i tag with class="fa")*** being used are not aligning vertically center to the parent element ***(a tag)***. I have been trying to solve this for a while but nothing works.

The output is as follow, the icons are always positioned to the top of the parent element. 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beffw.jpg)

```css
.navbar-default{
  background: #0099cc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.side-tool{
  position:  fixed;
  right: 1%;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 1040;
}

.side-tool a {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.side-tool a i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resource/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 left"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 middle"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="side-tool">
  <a href="#" class="go-top" style="display:inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="qr-code"><i class="fa fa-qrcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="favor-site"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: It's placed on the bottom right. Couldn't see the problem.

Comment: The expected output that the icon font shall stay in the right middle of each block, I mean, vertically and horizontally. But my code effect is the each icon-font stay in the top of block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.side-tool a i {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, the line-height of <i> should be set to same as its parent's height (<a>)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding `vertical-align: middle` to the `<i>` elements, you'll also need to add a `line-height` equal to the parent's `height` (`40px`):

```css
.navbar-default{
  background: #0099cc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.side-tool{
  position:  fixed;
  right: 1%;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 1040;
}

.side-tool a {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px; /* Added */
  display: inline-block;
}

.side-tool a i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resource/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 left"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 middle"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="side-tool">
  <a href="#" class="go-top" style="display:inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="qr-code"><i class="fa fa-qrcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="favor-site"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is because `vertical-alignment` is based on the `line-height` rather than the `height`. The `line-height` defaults at the height of the font, so in your example, the `vertical-alignment: middle` only sets an offset of the font's `18px` rather than the element's `40px` height.

`line-height` can be set either on the `<i>` element itself, or the parent `<a>` element.

Comment: line-height set on <i> works, but not take effect in <a>. So line-height and vertical-alignment shall in the same element, right?

Answer (score 0):

A couple different options for centering those icons in their `a` containers. I actually dont mind the absolute centering trick here:

Add to `.side-tool a`:

```
position: relative;
```

Replace the CSS targeting the icons with:

```
.side-tool a i {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Icons should be absolutely centered inside the 40x40 `a` tags.

Comment: I try it and all the icon font overlay on each other at the most bottom right

Comment: I had a typo. Make sure you have `position: relative;` on `.side-tool a`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the anchor tags into flex-boxes

```
.side-tool a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Adding this to your CSS should give you the results you want

```css
.navbar-default{
  background: #0099cc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.side-tool{
  position:  fixed;
  right: 1%;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 1040;
}

.side-tool a {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="resource/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 left"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 middle"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="side-tool">
  <a href="#" class="go-top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="qr-code"><i class="fa fa-qrcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="favor-site"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```